# NOT(Contains(TextField)) keyword in Email Templates

Tags: email-template, configuration

I have an issue when i am trying to use `NOT(Contains(TextField))` keyword in Custom email templates with multiple conditions

my code:

```
{!IF(OR(NOT(CONTAINS(Case.Engine__c,'AB')),NOT(CONTAINS(Case.Engine__c,'BC'))), 'my(Engines)','Print this')}<br/>
```

Example:
if my engine is RT, output is "my(Engines)"
, please help me to solve this issue, i am not getting output for mutliple conditions in IF conditions by using OR condition

Comment: If the output *is* `my(Engines)`, that would be correct based on how this is written. If you mean to say that `my(Engines)` is *expected*, but you're not getting that value, then you'd have a problem.

Comment: Yes, found the solution. thank you